# Http Authentication with PHP not working

Tags: php, http, authentication, cgi

I have Plesk Server where PHP is running as a CGI.

```
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

The above script should prompt the user name and password. (Yes it does)
After entering any user/pass it should print them. (No, it always ask for the user/pass)

How to fix it?

Comment: Are the headers the first thing to be output? (headers have to be the first thing to output or they wont work) (unless you have output buffering turned on)

Comment: PHP version/Web server name/version please...

Answer (score 20):

I've got this problem too on one of my servers and the following solved it for me. It's apparently due to using CGI.
http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

PHP:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: wow thanks! solved it for me. The website is hosted by the german hosting provider 1&1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the file I include before anything in any project that is under development:

```
<?php

// protecting page of unauthorized access

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){ 
    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    if ($user == 'username' && $pass == 'dev'){
        return;
    }
}

header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected zone"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'Login failed.';
exit;
```

Just include it in your `index.php` before anything else.

Comment: I am using it, and it perfectly works for me on more than one server. Perhaps your config is different somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding beow line to your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered using more standard .htaccess / .htpassword files (if you're using Apache)?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

Here $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] looks to be never setted, so it will always display this popup.

Comment: HTPASSWRD never worked here, that's why I decided to use PHP AUTH